# Traceback (most recent call last): File "/application/main.py", @bot.tree.command(name="ping", description="") NameError: name 'bot' is not defined

Tags: python

I'm trying to start my bot, but it keeps giving me this error: "Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/application/main.py", line 41, in      @bot.tree.command(name="ping", description="Cheque a latência do bot") NameError: name 'bot' is not defined"

This below is my code:      bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="whatever!", intents=discord.intents.all())       @bot.event     async def on_ready():         print("Being ready...")         try:             synced = await bot.tree.sync()             print(f"synced {len(synced)} commands sucessfully!")         except Exception as e:             print (e)           @bot.tree.command(name="ping", description="Cheque a latência do bot") async def ping(interaction:discord.Interaction):     await interaction.response.send_message(f"**Atualmente o meu ping é:**/n**`{round(bot.latency * 1000)}ms`**")"

Comment: That code is a hot mess.  Please edit the question to format it properly.

Comment: the error is here `NameError: name 'bot' is not defined"`  ...  but it is not possible to read your code currently.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example